# Rails View isn't refreshing after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm working on a sample Rails app that has Users, Events (that the user creates) and ultimately, Users will be able to subscribe / attend these events.

I have a table where users can subscribe and unsubscribe from events when they click a link_to button in the event row. The link_to calls a method from the event_controller that has a redirect to the current_path but when I click the button nothing happens to the view but it appears that the server renders the view.

Is this because I am calling it from the event_controller but using the show controller from User ?

LOG:

```
 Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (17.1ms)
```

Users > show.html.erb

```
    <% if current_user?(@user) %>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", e, method:  :delete,
                        data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></td>
    <% else %>
        <% if attendingEvent?(current_user, e.id) %>
            <td><%= link_to "Not Going", events_remove_event_to_attend_path(event_id: e.id, event_owner_id:@user.id, current_path:request.fullpath), remote: true %></td>
        <% else %>
            <td><%= link_to "I Want To Go", events_add_event_to_attend_path(event_id: e.id, event_owner_id:@user.id, current_path:request.fullpath), remote: true %></td>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

events_controller.rb

```
  def add_event_to_attend
    puts attend_params
    puts request.fullpath
    @attend = Attendee.new
    @attend.event_id = (attend_params[:event_id])
    @attend.user_id = current_user.id
    if @attend.save
      flash[:success] = "You created an assocations"
      redirect_to(attend_params[:current_path])
      puts 'saved'
    else
      flash[:danger] = "You did not create the event"
      puts 'not saved'
    end
  end

  def remove_event_to_attend
    @event_to_delete = Attendee.find_by_user_id_and_event_id(current_user.id,params[:event_id])
    @event_to_delete.destroy
    redirect_to(attend_params[:current_path])
  end
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. So... I notice you've put some `puts`es in your code... what do you see in the server logs/terminal screen? Secondly: what do you have in your rjs templates? you do have rjs templates right? You've made the links remote - which means you're sending a js request and the browser will only change its view if you send it back some js that tells it to do so. Alternatively, you can fix this quite quickly by removing `remote: true` from the links, and then the redirection will Just Work...

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.

So firstly... I notice you've put some `put`ses in your code... what do you see in the server logs/terminal screen?

Secondly: what do you have in your rjs templates? you do have rjs templates right? You've made the links remote - which means you're sending a js request and the browser will only change its view if you send it back some js that tells it to do so.

Alternatively, you can fix this quite quickly by removing `remote: true` from the links, and then the redirection will Just Work... because it's no longer a js-request and just an ordinary request.

Comment: Thank you so much Taryn!  It looks like it was the rjs which was a relic from a previous iteration! 

Thank you so much! I'll be sure to accept your answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new in Ruby on Rails too.

I'd like to add something to Taryn's answer. Maybe if you use `redirect_back fallback_location: asd_path`, asd_path being the name of the path of the same page (not for the same action), it could work.

I hope this helps, and welcome to Rails! I'm a newbie too, but rails is easy to learn! And I <3 Ruby, love at first sight.

**Quick note**: I'm using Rails 5, so if you're not using the same it may not work. Check in [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) (Be sure to check the same version you're using)